# How to break line using Bootstrap Columns?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have bootstrap columns where i have two `<p>` tags text so i can break line but its not working. What is right way to break lines in bootstrap ?

main.html

```
  <div class="col-md-12" ng-show="editControlToRisk">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8 fieldHeight">
            <p class="col-md-6 audit-block">Original Source System Control</P>
            <p>To Process Association ID:</p>
            <div class="col-md-4 alignedCtrlSourceId">{{controlDTO.controlInProcessDTO.externalId}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding `<br />`  this way

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-show="editControlToRisk">
    <div class="form-group col-md-8 fieldHeight">
        <p class="col-md-6 audit-block">Original Source System Control</p>
         <br />
        <p>To Process Association ID:</p>
        <div class="col-md-4 alignedCtrlSourceId">{{controlDTO.controlInProcessDTO.externalId}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*and attention to the case you have a `</P>` inside your code*